# How to get return value to label value

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Hi i have written this code and what I am trying in this code is to to get the return value of method to java swing label

here is my code:

```
public static int search(java.util.Date date)
    {

         Connection conn = null;
         ResultSet rs = null;
         Statement st = null;
           int b=0;
          try
          {

          conn=DBMgr.openConnection();      
          DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
          String dateStr=formatter.format(date);  
          System.out.println("date"+dateStr);
          String sqlQuery = "select sum(time_spend) as Time_Billed_Per_Day,datetime from time_entry  where datetime like '"+dateStr+"%' ";


              st = conn.createStatement();
               rs = st.executeQuery(sqlQuery); 

               while(rs.next())
              {

                      b = rs.getInt(1);
                     System.out.println("BILL of the date u specified is:"+b);         
               }
        }
        catch(SQLException ex) 
        {
             System.out.println(ex.toString());  
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {

                if(rs!=null)
                    rs.close();
                if(conn!=null)
                    DBMgr.closeConnection(conn);
            }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
           }

        }
      return b;
      }
```

This is swings code:

```
JLabel lblTimeBilledDayText = new JLabel( "00:45:20" , JLabel.RIGHT);
pnlOuter.add(lblTimeBilledDayText);
```

I want to get the return value of method in place of "00:45:20"

How to do this?

Comment: Which is the `String` you want to put in the label? Your method is returning an `int`...

Comment: return value of which method? Since that parameter ("00:45:20") is a String, you will need a method which returns a String to pass there.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The problem is that the return value doesn't have a for at. You're going to need to write your own formatter to get the duration in the String format you need. The rest is simple

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
JLabel lblTimeBilledDayText = new JLabel(String.valueOf(search(date)) , JLabel.RIGHT);
pnlOuter.add(lblTimeBilledDayText);
```

Comment: Consider using `String.valueOf` instead of the String concatenation `+""` which is far more expensive.

Answer (score 5):

If b is the return int value then

```
JLabel lblTimeBilledDayText = new JLabel(new String(Integer.toString(b)), JLabel.RIGHT);
pnlOuter.add(lblTimeBilledDayText);
```

Comment: the wraping `new String()` is not needed as `String` is immutable

Answer (score 5):

```
int searchResult = search( date);
// convert to String. You might want to opt for a method 
// which offers more formatting options
String searchResultAsString = Integer.toString( searchResult );

JLabel lblTimeBilledDayText = new JLabel( searchResultAsString , JLabel.RIGHT);
pnlOuter.add(lblTimeBilledDayText);
```

That being said, you should not be mixing database queries and Swing objects modifications/creation on the same thread. Swing objects must be handled on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) and long-running operations (like e.g. a database query) should not be executed on the EDT as the UI will be blocked/unresponsive while the operation takes place.

Take a look at the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) tutorial for more info. A typical solution is to perform the query on a worker thread using a `SwingWorker`. When the query is finished, the `SwingWorker` has an easy mechanism to update your Swing components on the correct thread.

Answer (score 3):

JLabel lblTimeBilledDayText = new JLabel(search(@year,@month,@date,00,45,20) , JLabel.RIGHT);